# List not defined when importing a function

Tags: python, function, module

I made two modules in Python. The other one is a sentinel-controlled loop that asks for the data and the other module contains the functions needed for computation. When I import Module 2 (module with functions), I get a Name Error.

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

where x is the argument of my function
convert(x)

but x is a defined list in Module 1 (sentinel-controlled loop) where I store data. I can't figure out why the imported module does not consider it.

I imported the other module as

```
import ModuleName
```

What could be the problem?

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner in Python so I'm not really very familiar with it.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: I don't know if I can post it here since this is an assignment but I can send it maybe. @Janukasamaranyake

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nostalgiaultra No need to post your full code. Make a minimal example that regenerates the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way you import. There are a couple of ways to resolve this.

In the example below, you import `module_name` and then call function `x` in the proper namespace.

```py
import module_name

module_name.x()
```

Another way would be to explicitly import function `x` from `module_name`.

```py
from module_name import x

x()
```

I highly advise you to do some reading on how importing works in python, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp) is always a good starting point.